# SQL : stored procedure: all columns are updated instead of the one's selected in the where

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures

I want only the risico columns adjusted where `aantalDeelnames = 1` but the code sets them all to 1.

```
drop procedure if exists VulRisico
go

create procedure VulRisico
as
begin
    update autos
    set risico = 1
    from (select leden.lidnaam, autos.risico, count(deelnemers.evenementnr)as aantalDeelnames
          from leden
          join autos on leden.lidnr = autos.lidnr
          join deelnemers on autos.autonr = deelnemers.autonr
          group by leden.lidnaam, autos.risico) as query
   where query.aantalDeelnames = 1
end

exec VulRisico
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

All the rows are updated because there is no "connection" between the `autos` and the query.

If you write the query like this, it is obvious that all (or no) rows in `autos` would be updated by the query:

```
update a
    set risico = 1
    from autos a cross join
         (select l.lidnaam, a.risico, count(*) as aantalDeelnames
          from leden l join
               autos a
               on l.lidnr = a.lidnr join
               deelnemers d
               on a.autonr = d.autonr
           group by l.lidnaam, a.risico
          ) query   
   where query.aantalDeelnames = 1
```

Unfortunately, you have not provided an explanation of what you want to accomplish or sample data/desired results.  This explains your problem -- and answers this question.  If you want a working query, I would recommend asking *another* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.